# "python -m django --version" 1.11.18 Cannot update to 2.1

Tags: django, python-2.7

I watched a tutorial that requires me to have Django 2.1.

When I type in "python -m django --version" - my Ubuntu terminal says 1.11.18 But, when I type "django-admin --version" - terminal says 2.1 This didn't bother me until I reached part 6 of this series, I'm heavily invested now with a serious problem I can't figure out. I even completely reinstalled my OS, (I was running Linux mint, thought it'd be easier if I ran Ubuntu) I ran through a myriad of different "fixes" I found online, but nothing seemed to fix this.
The main issue that I ran into from the tutorial is the urls linking.

EDIT:
I have Python 3.6 installed

Comment: Are you using a venv it virtualenv? That would probably solve a few of your issues. I'm betting you may have one version installed with the system python, and another in an environment.

Comment: No, Im not sure how or what venv it virtualenv is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using Python-3 to use Django-2.1. Django 1.11 is the last version to support Python 2.7.

Comment: I have Python-3 installed

Comment: make sure you're running your commands as Python3 instead of just python

Comment: How do I know the difference?

Comment: Run `python --version` to know

Comment: python3 will run with python-3. your better off creating a virtualenv (virtualenv -p Python3 virtualenvname) if your on Ubuntu(not sure what other distros use the same command) and then installing django there instead. make sure you have virtualenv installed first tho

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely because you've got both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on your system, and you're installing Django without a virtual environment. I would highly recommend using a virtual environment: it keeps your project separated from the system Python version's packages. At this point, using Python 3 and `venv` to make your virtual environment is the best practice.

See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

Here's a quick walkthrough to create a new virtual environment in a directory called "my_django_project" in your home directory with Python 3 and install Django:

```
python3 -m venv ~/my_django_project
pip install Django
. ~/my_django_project/bin/activate
```

To deactivate your virtual environment, type `deactivate`.

Then, whenever you want to work on this project, type `. ~/my_django_project/bin/activate`.

Now let's say you wanted to work on a separate project using another Python package, like OpenCV. You could create a separate virtual environment for this project:

```
python3 -m venv ~/my_opencv_project
pip install opencv
. ~/my_opencv_project/bin/activate
```

This allowed you to keep your projects separate. There is a fair amount more to learn, but this should be enough to get you started. Good luck!